# How to create a flyout menu with Views?

Tags: views, routes, theming

I am trying to achieve the following output- id like a view with two images- each displaying a corresponding menu on hover- I've looked at using rewrite result for an image field in views for this- but I don't think I am using it properly. I would be tremendously grateful if anybody could take the time to give me some tips or tutorials on how to do this?

Note: I am a drupal-newbie.

Comment: are you need to do something or have problem to achieve with drupal?
Please write more details about what you need/have? we could help better in that case

Comment: Your question is not clear enough. Can you please provide more detail on what you wanna achieve and what have you did yet?

Comment: For a expandable menu, I believe superfish module should be used instead of views.

Answer (score 3):

Views maybe isn't the best solution to your problem. Drupal has a built in way to create menus. When you created your two menus and maybe placed them on your site with [Menu Block](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_block), you then may apply the flyout functionality with CSS or jQuery or have a look at [Superfish](https://www.drupal.org/project/superfish) maybe.